# How do you use the open verb in Image Events using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, image-editing

According to the dictionary for Image Events, the `open` verb is supposed to return a document object. This is also how it's used in multiple online examples.

However, when I try to use it, the script <del>correctly</del> opens the file in Preview, and does not return anything. Even when I try the following example, from Apple's own [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ManipulateImages.html), I get a "Can’t get properties of missing value." number -1728 from properties of missing value.

How are you meant to get an image object from an existing file in order to manipulate it with other actions from Image Events?

I'm on Big Sur 11.6.2 in case this doesn't affect older/newer releases.

```
-- Prompt for an image
set theImageFile to choose file of type "public.image" with prompt ""

-- Launch Image Events
tell application "Image Events"
    launch
    
    -- Open the image
    set theImage to open theImageFile
    
    -- Read the image's properties
    tell theImage
        properties
        --> {color space:RGB, image file:file "Macintosh HD:Users:YourUserName:Desktop:My Image.png" of application "Image Events", bit depth:millions of colors, dimensions:{293, 252}, location:folder "Macintosh HD:Users:YourUserName:Desktop:" of application "Image Events", embedded profile:profile "Thunderbolt Display" of image "My Image.png" of application "Image Events", file type:PNG, class:image, name:"My Image.png", resolution:{72.0, 72.0}}
        
        -- Read the image's resolution
        resolution
        --> {72.0, 72.0}
        
        -- Read the image's type
        file type
        --> PNG
        
        -- Read the name of the image's embedded profile
        name of embedded profile
        --> "Thunderbolt Display"
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Using 'open' in Image Events doesn't open a file in a GUI app (e.g. Preview). It opens the image that's stored within the file. As the documentation you reference suggests, you shouldn't see anything as Image Events is a background app. Your code above works fine in Sierra (including returning an image object) so maybe it's a Big Sur thing.

Comment: Something to try… insert this immediately below your 'set theImageFile…' line: `set theImagefile to POSIX path of theImagefile`. What it does is get a posix path reference to the alias that the first line generates. Image Events can use either format, and there have been some issues around aliases in Big Sur.

Comment: @Mockman, thank you for checking. It seems like the `open` verb infuriatingly disregards the tell block that it's inside, and always opens a document in Preview. To test this, I placed it inside a `tell application "Pixelmator Pro"` block and it _still_ opened the image in Preview.

Comment: @Mockman, I just tried the workaround you suggested and it worked! Please add it as an answer so that I can mark it as being correct :)

Comment: Interesting, but not in a good way. I wonder how you are supposed to know some of these outcomes. Out of curiosity, what happens if you combine 'tell' and 'open' like this: `tell application "Image Events" to open theImageFile`. You could then follow with `set theImage to the result` and hopefully be in the same place.

Comment: The following works only if `theImageFile` had been converted to a POSIX path. `theImage` is otherwise still a missing value. Interestingly, it's not opening Preview when used like this.
```lang-applescript
tell application "Image Events" to open theImageFile
set theImage to the result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this immediately below your `set theImageFile…` line:

```
set theImagefile to POSIX path of theImagefile
```

This gets a posix path reference to the alias that the first line generated. Image Events can use either format, and there have been some issues around aliases in Big Sur.